"extrude" bézier line along hair curve
I'm trying to create a curl curve hair setup that creates a a long mesh to apply a simple texture to it, but I don't want to use a closed curve like a circle to generate the shape. Instead, I'm trying to use a curve line.
For now I have this setup:

Ho Can I fix the extrusion to make the line have this shape:

